# Is it possible to stabilize every system with an integrator

Tags: operational-amplifier, stability, integrator

I was wondering if it was possible to stabilize every system with an integrator. From my point of view, an integrator can be used for applying a dominant pole strategy.

If I place the pole at very low frequency, the phase shift will be 90°C for the low frequencies part of the system. Then at higher frequencies, whatever the phase shift is, the gain will be lower than 0. Would placing the pole at very very very low frequency, an integrator should stabilize every system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. If the system you want to control itself contains an integrator, adding another integrator will make it unstable, no matter how low you choose your pole to be. This is because the pole of the system is at omega=zero, so you can't insert a dominant pole. You can't go lower than 0 Hz, after all. The phase lag through the feedback loop will be 180° or greater, making it oscillate.

The way to stabilize such a control loop would be to omit the integrator and use proportional and differential gain only. (Depending on the order of the integrator in the system, you might even go for a 2nd order differentiator, aka two cascaded differentiators.)

I've had to work with such a system lately at university: a model maglev train. The physical system integrates force (from an electromagnet) into velocity, and velocity into position, making it a 2nd order integrator that can't be compensated with a dominant pole as its two poles are at 0 Hz.

Comment: Ok I see :) I do not think that I already have an integrator into my system or a transfer function with a pole at the origin

Comment: In that case, it might very well be possible to stabilize that particular system with a dominant pole compensation scheme. But not every system in existence! :)

Answer (score 1):

> *Is it possible to stabilize every system with an integrator*

An integrator produces a phase lag of 90° and, adding this to some systems will definitely cause instability. I mean, you asked if "every system" could be stabilized by using an integrator and the answer has to be a big fat no!